# Char to represent hex number from int with prefix '0x0'

Tags: c++, formatting, hex

**My goal:** I'm building an application using MFC in Visual Studio 2015. I created a table with two columns which hold the numbers and values of many registers, and looks as follows:

[image]

to fill this table in a convenient way, I want to create a for loop which will send LPCSTR string (which automatically interpreted as const char) to member function of CListCtrl class which is called [InsertItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=vs-2019#insertitem). I want this LPCSTR string to look like a hex number 0x01 or 0x14 when the value after the prefix 0x will be determined by the index of the loop in hex base. for example:

```
char buffer[3*sizeof(int)];
int l_iItem;
for (int index = REGS_NUMBER; index >= 0; index--) {
        // Somehow make buffer look like 0xN when N is the index value in hex representation stuffed with 
        // zeroes if needed;
        l_iItem = m_EditableList.InsertItem(LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_STATE, 0, buffer, 0, LVIS_SELECTED, 0, 0);
        m_EditableList.SetItemText(l_iItem, 1, "00000000");
```

I've saw many questions regarding this subject, but almost all of them suggested a way to solve this which is suitable only if I want to print the number to the standard output, but I want to print it to char type variable (as was well said at the comments). I'd be thankful if anyone could refer me to the adequate function.

Thank you.

===========================================================================

As Tushar suggested I tried adding those headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
```

and tried running the following code:

```
    char* n;
    
    int i = 7;
    //std::istringstream s("2A");


    n << std::hex << std::showbase << i;

    std::cout << n;
```

the errors I get:

```
expression must have integral or unscoped enum.
'hex' is not a member of std.
'showbase' is not a member of std.
undeclared identifier.
undeclared identifier.
```

another trial: as was suggested int he comments, I tried using ostringstream instead of char* as follows:

```
    std::ostringstream ss;
    int i = 7;
    ss << std::hex << std::showbase << i;

    std::string str = ss.str();
    const char *output = str.c_str();
```

I'm getting the same errors, although I included all the necessary headers. what could be the problem?

Comment: Create a `char` array and use `fprintf` to write the number to it.

Comment: Printing *is*  what you want to do, but you want to "print" to a string rather than to the console. Read about `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: `<< std::hex` doesn't work on `char*`. It's part of the IOStreams section of the Standard Library. It will work on `std::cout`, `std::ofstream`, `std::ostringstream` and the likes.

Answer (score 0):

> ios_base& hex (ios_base& str);

It is used to sets the basefield format flag for the str stream to hex. When basefield is set to hex, integer values inserted into the stream are expressed in hexadecimal base (i.e., radix 16). For input streams, extracted values are also expected to be expressed in hexadecimal base when this flag is set.

If you want to parse the string in hex base

> std::istringstream("2A") >> std::hex >> n;

Example of using hex base.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Parsing string \"10 0x10 010\"\n";
 
    int n1, n2, n3;
    std::istringstream s("10 0x10 010");
    s >> std::setbase(16) >> n1 >> n2 >> n3;
    std::cout << "hexadecimal parse: " << n1 << ' ' << n2 << ' ' << n3 << '\n';
     s >> std::setbase(0) >> n1 >> n2 >> n3;
    std::cout << "prefix-dependent parse: " << n1 << ' ' << n2 << ' ' << n3 << '\n';
 
    std::cout << "hex output: " << std::setbase(16)
              << std::showbase << n1 << ' ' << n2 << ' ' << n3 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I can't make it work. could you please give me an example? also, It doesn't exactly solve my problem since I want it to also have a prefix of "0x0" or just "0x" depending on the length of the integer (i.e. 0x01 or 0x15)

Comment: I don't understand what you are exactly doing. Will make more sense if you show some more code